# How to solve "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 on godaddy server

Tags: php, laravel-5

**NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161. Here is my route code it's working fine on localhost but when i am trying to access my route on godaddy server i am getting notfoundhttpexception here is my route code.**

```
Route::get('/customers','Controller@mainpage');  
Route::get('/products','Controller@productpage'); 
Route::get('/brokers','Controller@brokerpage'); 
Route::get('/trucks','Controller@truckpage');
Route::get('/workers','Controller@workerpage');
```

**My controller code is below.**

```
public function mainpage()
{
$data['tableresult']=DB::table('customers')->get();
return view('main',$data);
}


public function productpage()
{
$data['tableresult']=DB::table('products')->get();
return view('products',$data);
}

public function truckpage()
{
$data['tableresult']=DB::table('trucks')->get();
return view('truck',$data);
}

public function brokerpage()
{
$data['tableresult']=DB::table('broker')->get();
return view('broker',$data);
}
```

**This url is working fine on localhost** 
    http://localhost:82/logistic/public/customers

**When i am trying to access my project on live server i am getting notfoundhttpexception here is the url of live server**

```
 http://www.welcometransports.com/public/customers
```

Comment: But you have no code for customers, out 4 out of 5

Comment: what do you mean i have no code for customers?

Comment: i am trying to get the mainpage method from customers